# How to Disable CTRL + K + D in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a requirement that i do not need to change a line of code in existing lines and when i do control K D it formats all the data and can see lots of changes in SVN so please i want to Disable CTRL + K + D in Visual studio,.

Comment: Um, don't press this shortcut? I don't get it.

Comment: I just want to disable in studio if some one press it it should not format it.

Comment: So you want to disable this feature in Visual Studio of _other people_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it in the Options:

[image: some text filler because this is a short answer.]

Comment: I was just wondering how do i again enable it. Currently i have removed.